# Adding days to datetime

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

I wan't to add to planned date integer. It's always will be from 1 to 10, but having problem with my code.

```
planned_date = fields.Date(string='Planned Date', required=False,
                           default=fields.Date.today)
def linedate(self):    
    if line.discount > 5:
       
        daysz = line.product_id.seller_ids[0].delay # it's integer from 1 to 10 always
   
        planned = (line.planned_date + timedelta(days=daysz) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        line.planned_date =  planned
        print line.planned_date
```

I'm getting this kind of error

> planned = (line.planned_date + timedelta(days=daysz) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>
> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.timedelta found

Comment: Looks like `line.planned_date ` is a string. Can you show a print of it?

Comment: I just checked type it's <type 'unicode'>

Comment: Yes, You need to convert it to a datetime object and then add the required timedelta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line.planned_date` is a Unicode string object. You need to convert it to a datetime object and then add using timedelta.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
planned = (datetime.datetime.strptime(line.planned_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=daysz) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I would advise to use Odoo's internal conversion `fields.Date.from_string()` for it, because you don't need to fiddle around with formats. And ofcourse the other way around `fields.Date.to_string()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `planned_date` because Odoo stores dates as strings ans it would be better to use Date methods to convert from string and to Date objects, You can refer to [Odoo fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#fields).

> > static from_string(value): Convert an ORM value into a date value.
> >
> > static to_string(value): Convert a date value into the format expected by the ORM.

```
    def linedate(self):
    if line.discount > 5:
        daysz = line.product_id.seller_ids[0].delay  # it's integer from 1 to 10 always

        planned = fields.Date.from_string(line.planned_date) + timedelta(days=daysz)
        line.planned_date = fields.Date.to_string(planned)
        print line.planned_date
```

Comment: In Odoo context the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install `dateutil` (`pip install python-dateutil`) and then you can easily parse `line.planned_date` to datetime object

```
from dateutil import parser
planned = (parser.parse(line.planned_date) + timedelta(days=daysz) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: sorry but it's not possible to use external librarys

Comment: If you can't install `dateutil`, use the method @rakesh has suggested; but make sure `line.planned_date` is specified in  `%Y-%m-%d` format. If not adjust the format